# CollapsiblePanelExtender doesn't expand

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm currently working on a project which uses the AjaxControlToolkit.
The panel collapses just fine, but won't expand afterwards or, if collapsed by default, won't expand initially.

I can't find the error in my markup. please help

```
<cc2:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="server" CollapseControlID="oben_ausbildung"
                ExpandControlID="oben_ausbildung" TargetControlID="unten_ausbildung" Collapsed="True" ImageControlID="i_einaufklapp" 
                ExpandedImage="~/gesichert/images/panel_einklappen.jpg" CollapsedImage="~/gesichert/images/panel_erweitern.jpg">
            </cc2:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Comment: Extender's markup seems to be fine. Can you please share also markup of other relevant controls (at least ones with IDs `oben_ausbildung` and `unten_ausbildung`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late for an answer, but nevertheoless:
The problem was related to the Scriptmanager. In addition, the old live version of the application had the same problem for about 1 year and nobody noticed it.
Switching from  to  proved to be a workaround for us.

Regards.